# How to make a customisable navigation bar title? Swift 4

Tags: swift4.1, xcode9.3

I have a textfield on my firstViewController and what I want to happen is: once the user entered a text and goes to the SecondViewController it will become the navigation bar title.

I'm new at programming and I was hoping someone could help me.

[image: First View controller]

[image: Second View controller]

Comment: How you are navigating to another view controller

Comment: by using tableviewDidSelectRow: performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)

Comment: See answer below

Answer (score 1):

First way to navigate creating object of view controller and navigate through navigation controller

```
let second = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SecondViewController") as!  SecondViewController
second.title = textTitle.text!
navigationController?.pushViewController(second, animated: true)
```

Second way to navigate from storyboard

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard  segue.identifier == "segueIdentifier" else { return }
        let destination = segue.destination as? SecondViewController
        destination?.strTitle = textTitle.text!
}
```

In second view controller add this

```
var strTitle : String?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.title = strTitle ?? "default string"
}
```

Comment: I put this in tableViewDidSelectRow:       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        myBudget = [indexPath.row]
//        performSegue(withIdentifier: "segue", sender: self)
        
            func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
            guard  segue.identifier == "segue" else { return }
            let destination = segue.destination as? SecondViewController
            destination?.strTitle = myBudgetTitle.text!
        }
        }  -but it won't let me go to secondViewController

Comment: did you added push segue. and put perform segue in the view controller.  I cant "override" in your code. You have to override this function in your first view controller.

Comment: I think you should follow this tutorial 
https://www.appcoda.com/storyboards-ios-tutorial-pass-data-between-view-controller-with-segue/

Answer (score 0):

**Can you try @ChanWarde way but present the view controller rather than using segues ?**

```
let second = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
"SecondViewController") as!  SecondViewController
second.title = textTitle.text!
present(second, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

**Or try:**

```
let second = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: 
"SecondViewController") as!  SecondViewController
second.title = textTitle.text!

DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController = second()
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
})
```

Comment: I did it. my fault. I forgot to fill up the storyboard id. the view controller now is being presented. but the navigation bar in the secondViewController disappeared. why is that so?

Comment: Which code are you using to display the secondViewController?

Comment: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        myBudget = [indexPath.row]
        let second = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:
            "segue") as!  SecondViewController
        second.strTitle = myBudgetTitle.text!
        present(second, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

Comment: and at the SecondViewController. I used self.navigationItem.title = strTitle ?? "default string" in viewdidload

Comment: If you're using a navigation controller then you'll have to follow @ChanWarde  code. If you have your own custom navbars in your viewControllers then presenting won't be a problem.